# How to deploy renamed the custom object tab using package.xml?

Tags: deployment, metadata, tab, package.xml

I renamed a custom object tab name from 'ABC' to 'XYZ' in `Customize > Tab Names and Labels > Edit`. How can i deploy this change through eclipse using package.xml.

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy the custom tabs through package.xml in the following way:

```
 <types>
    <members>API name of the Object</members>
    <name>CustomTab</name>
 </types>
```

and include the ObjectName.tab file also

Comment: but i changed the tab name not in the object level, changed in Tab Names and Labels in customize. I couldn't see any diff in existing tab and current tab.

Comment: We have a .tab file also for custom tabs. Add that file also.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the objectTranslations. There are multiple files in this folder based on languages eg: for Account in english there is Account-en_US.objectTranslation and so on ... . Find the file that has your changes and deploy it

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to rename the tab. The package.xml file cannot do this. Leave the file name for the tab the same. Retrieve the metadata for the tab, change the label field, and then deploy the tab. This will change the label. The XML will look something like this, below. Note the "label" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <frameHeight>600</frameHeight>
    <hasSidebar>false</hasSidebar>
    <label>EDIT_ME</label>
    <mobileReady>false</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom73: Highway Sign</motif>
    <url>https://www.website.com/somepage.html</url>
    <urlEncodingKey>UTF-8</urlEncodingKey>
</CustomTab>
```